FlutterFire Android Google Authentication Fails
I am working from the codelabs tutorial: https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/firebase-auth-in-flutter-apps#0 I can log in with email and password. I have also added a Google authentication  provider, but login attempts using this provider always fail with "An unknown error occurred" after I select my Google account.  I would appreciate help with how to track this error down (for example, are there logs somewhere?) or with possible causes for the error.
I am passing the web client ID to the Google provider, and I have added a debug SHA-1 fingerprint to the Android application in Firebase.
I have tried rebooting the Android emulator, toggling Google authentication off and on in Firebase, redownloading google-services.json, using the oAuth client ID instead of the web client ID.
I am expecting to be able to log in.
Thanks very much.

are you getting any specific error code while login? if yes please share those details as well.

Hi, Dhruvan.  Thanks for your help.  I have regenerated the SHA-1 fingerprint, added yhe new fingerprint to Firebase for the app, updated my google-services.json and now login is working.  -Dan

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I have regenerated the SHA-1 fingerprint, added the new fingerprint to Firebase for the app, updated my google-services.json and now Google login is working.
